# Why is my render image only consists of bright patterns?

Tags: rendering

It is supposed to be a ball and a structure next to it
but the render image only display this
can anyone tell me why and how to make it normal?
[image]

Comment: Consider sharing the blend file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ or provide more info with imagery https://getsharex.com/ , https://ezgif.com/optimize